# Apache does not want to fopen or fwrite in FIFO (pipe)

Tags: php, c++, linux, apache, pipe

I've been having a problem with setting up a proper communication between a .cpp file and .html one.

So I have three files: one is a .cpp server, creating pipe and blocking on it until a message comes, .php file opening pipe and writing something into it and a .html file, which has just a button, running the script.

What is unusual is that when I run my server and then run php script from console everything works perfectly, but if I want to do it via browser and html page - the pipe cannot be opened.

Php and html files are placed in /var/www/html/ catalog and my cpp file is in my home folder.

I am trying to create pipe in /tmp/ folder.

I tried changing chmod and chown permissions to both of those path (and I know that apache = www-data) but as now to no avail. I have 100% NOT installed SELinux.

I really really appreciate any help, I've been trying to figure this out for several hours now...

**server.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std; 

const char MSG_LENGTH = 9; 
string FIFO_1 = "/tmp/fifo"; 

int main() {

    if ( mkfifo(FIFO_1.c_str(), S_IFIFO | 0666 ) == -1 ) {
        cout << "Cannot create fifo" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }

    cout << "Fifo created" << endl;

    int readfd = open(FIFO_1.c_str(), O_RDONLY); 
    if ( readfd < 0 ) {
        cout << "Cannot open fifo" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }

    char buffer[1024]; 
    if ( read(readfd, buffer, MSG_LENGTH) < 1 ) {
        cout << "Cannot read from fifo" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }
    buffer[MSG_LENGTH] = '\0'; 

    cout << "Message: " << buffer << endl; 

    close(readfd); 
    unlink(FIFO_1.c_str()); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**function.php**

```
<?php

    $pipe_name = '/tmp/fifo'; 
    $msg = "message"; 

    $pipe = fopen($pipe_name, 'w'); 
    if ( $pipe == false) 
        echo "Cannot open fifo"; 

    if ( fwrite($pipe, $msg) == false ) 
        echo 'Cannot write to fifo';
    else 
        echo 'Can write to fifo'; 

?>
```

Comment: So, are you sure that /tmp/fifo isn't inside your /var/www/... root?

Comment: yes, I am sure, it is in fact in /tmp/. actually, if I change the directory where my pipe is created I still cannot open the pipe via http in my php file

Comment: I mean "do you know for sure that your `$pipe= fopen($pipe_name, 'w');` doesn't open the file in a different directory than your "server"? This is certainly how my PHP code behaves (that / in PHP is not the same as / in my filesystem)

Comment: I was able to get your code to work, but struggle a bit with the synchronisation between the server and the web-page, when trying to do it in reverse (so I could actually show something for it on the web-page that I set up).

Comment: You may want to try ` $err = error_get_last(); echo "Err = "; var_dump($err); echo "<br/>";` or similar, to see what the exact error is that you are getting.

Comment: Actually, it may be working now: 
http://linuxhost.matsp.co.uk/calculator/pipe.php

Comment: I've now taken down the pipe.php page, since it has "served its purpose".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that I'm running:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std; 

string FIFO_1 = "/blah/fifo"; 

int main() {

    if ( mkfifo(FIFO_1.c_str(), S_IFIFO | 0666 ) == -1 ) {
        cout << "Cannot create fifo" << endl; 
//        return 1; 
    }
    else
    {
    cout << "Fifo created" << endl;
    }

    int readfd = open(FIFO_1.c_str(), O_WRONLY); 
    if ( readfd < 0 ) {
        cout << "Cannot open fifo" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }

    int count = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
    count++;
    cout << "Sending message " << count << endl;
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    string msg = ctime(&t);
    if ( write(readfd, msg.c_str(), msg.length()) < 1 ) {
        cout << "Cannot write to fifo" << endl; 
        return 1; 
    }
    sleep(1);
    }

    close(readfd); 
//    unlink(FIFO_1.c_str()); 

    return 0; 
}
```

And the PHP code:

```
<?php

$pipe_name = '/blah/fifo'; 
$msg = "";

$pipe = fopen($pipe_name, 'r'); 
if ( $pipe == false) 
{
    echo "Cannot open fifo<br/>";
    $err = error_get_last();
    var_dump($err);
}
else
{   
    $count = 0;
    $data = stream_get_meta_data($pipe);
    var_dump($data);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo date("Y-M-d H:i:s") . "<br/>";
    echo "Waiting for message:";
    while(1)
    {
        $msg = fgets($pipe, 30);
        $err = error_get_last();
        if ($err)
        {
            echo "Err = "; var_dump($err); echo "<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Got = " . $msg . "<br/>";
        }
        $count ++;
        if ($count > 20)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

echo "<br/>Done...";

?>
```

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you so much! I've spent so much time trying to look for proper permissions etc. and it still wasn't it! I looked at error.log file but still the errors weren't clear enough.

Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver :)

Comment: So, I take it that `error_get_last()` gave you some clue?